# como formatar um retorno f strings python de forma visualmente limpa?

Tags: python-3.x, return

O código a seguir foi fruto de uma prática com listas, onde o programa deve exibir o resultado de uma competição de saltos realizada onde cada competidor tem direito a cinco saltos antes de ser feita a média simples que determina o vencedor. Devem ser exibidas as iterações de saltos para cada competidor e a média. A seguir, o código e as dúvidas:

```
nome = " "

def media_salto (nome, salto):
    media = 0
    for s in range(0,5):
        media += salto[s]
    media /=5
    
    
    return (f"\nResultado final:\nnome: {nome} \nsaltos: {salto[0]} - {salto[1]} - {salto[2]} - {salto[3]} - {salto[4]}\nmedia dos saltos: {(media):.2f} m\n")
    
    
    
while (nome):
    nome = ""
    salto = []
    nome = input(f"Atleta: {nome.title()}")
    if (nome):
        for s in range (0,5):
            salto.append((input(f"Tamanho do salto {s+1}: ")))
    
            salto[s] = salto[s].split(" m")
            del salto[s][1]
            salto[s] = float(salto[s][0])
            
    
    print(media_salto(nome,salto))
```

Como pode ser atestado, embora funcional o return efetuado não é o mais visualmente limpo e a dúvida central do post é neste ponto. Tentei dividir as f strings em mais de uma dentro do return para que o código ficasse mais organizado, mas obtive erro e só consegui fazer o return em linha única, alguma sugestão?

Agradeço desde já, fiquem á vontade para sugerir qualquer outra coisa no código, já que ainda estou começando.

Comment: Em vez de `salto[0]`, `salto[1]`, etc, pode ser `' - '.join(salto)`, não sei se fica mais "limpo", mas com certeza fica melhor porque assim funciona independente da quantidade de elementos na lista (da forma que vc fez, só funciona se tiver exatamente 5). Inclusive, a média pode ser calculada mais facilmente com `media = sum(salto) / len(salto)`

Comment: Corrigindo, teria que ser `' - '.join(map(str, saltos))` (tem que converter os valores dos saltos para string senão o `join` dá erro). E também dá pra simplificar a leitura dos dados: https://ideone.com/KaLW2g